# Is there a list of pilot programs published?

Tags: pilot

I am always looking to push to boundaries of Salesforce and find a lot of limitations on a day to day basis.

Is there is a list of pilot programs available for customers or partners to view and apply for?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's comprehensive, but you can filter `Ideas` based on those which are in [Pilot/Beta](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch?pageNo=3&filter=Pilot%2FBeta).